# access to repository forbidden

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am getting access for repository forbidden while checking out the repository of svn. I have imported an existing repository in the newly installed svn server. All username and password are correct only. Kindly help.

If i access the url from browser then getting below error.
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource

The error from the 'VisualSVN Server' event log:

> Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNSubversionReposRelativeAccessFile: An
> authz rule refers to group 'admin', which is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add permissions](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions) for your user account to access the imported repository. Having an account and knowing its password is insufficient. You need to grant this account access to your repository or project.

You need to follow these steps:

1. Start the VisualSVN Server Manager console,
2. Expand the Repositories node,
3. Right-click the Repository and click Properties.
4. Click the Security tab.
5. Configure permissions for your user account on the Security tab and click Apply.

Note that you can also configure permissions using [PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00165/).

See the article [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) for more information.

PS If these steps don't help, then you need to check the 'VisualSVN Server' event log in Windows Event Viewer. Do you see any errors?

**Update #1**

So we've found out the actual error message in the log:

> Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNSubversionReposRelativeAccessFile: An
> authz rule refers to group 'admin', which is undefined

It appears that there is a reference to a non-existent group in the file `\path-to-repository-on-disk\conf\VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini` (e.g., `D:\Repositories\MyRepo\conf\VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini`).

Possible reasons:

- You were migrating your repositories from another VisualSVN Server instance and you did not copy the `groups.conf` file (e.g., `D:\Repositories\groups.conf`. The file `groups.conf` has a list of groups for the standalone Subversion authentication mode. Groups you've granted permissions to must be present in the file.
- You somehow manually added a non-existent group into the `VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini` file. Perhaps again you've copied the file from somewhere without copying other configuration files, or you added the line into the authz file using notepad.exe.

To resolve the problem you may choose from these two different options:

- **Option A:** Delete the `VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini` file and configure the permissions from scratch using VisualSVN Server Manager.
- **Option B:** If you are migrating the repositories from another VisualSVN Server installation, make sure to copy the `groups.conf` and `htpasswd` files into the D:\Repositories directory on the new server. The first file has group account and describes their members. The second file has user account names and password hashes.

In either case, you need to review repository permissions after resolving the error.

Comment: I have tried these steps after deleting the existing groups and users. Have created a new user and gave the fresh permissions but still getting the same error. Please note that i have created a fresh repository and tried accessing that and i am not getting any error in that. How do i see even logs? Please guide.

Comment: @Vikas using Windows Event Viewer, check the 'VisualSVN Server' event log: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/. And show 1. the exact error message. 2. a screenshot of the Security tab 3. events from the 'VisualSVN Server' log.

Comment: Failed to load the AuthzVisualSVNSubversionReposRelativeAccessFile: An authz rule refers to group 'admin', which is undefined getting this in event log

Comment: after following the steps not that error is gone but one error is still there
Access denied: 'user' GET <repo_name>:/

and in the browser forbidden error is still there

Comment: @Vikas now you need to add permissions for your user account.

Comment: permissions given to the users of read/write on the repository. Could this be an issue of version mismatch as previous version which i was using of 2017 and currently I'm using latest version.

Comment: @Vikas the "Access denied" error just by itself means that your user account does not have permissions to the repository or repository path you are trying to access. I don't see what to troubleshoot now besides properly configuring the permissions for your account. See https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/.

Comment: I figured out the mismatch in the versions. I have installed the version which was formatted and tried importing the repository. There is no error now. Thanks for the help !!

Comment: @Vikas great! You may upvote and accept the answer if it helped.